# How to connect admin dashboard to a MERN e-commerce app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, admin, mern

I am working on an e-commerce app with React.js as the frontend and Node.js/Express.js as the backend. But how can I create a dashboard for myself to add/delete/edit items for the app? If I create another React.js app as the admin app and send requests to the backend then there will be two frontends for one backend. How will I able to deploy them to Heroku? So please suggest me the best way to create a dashboard without using any external library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have 2 frontend application for one backend service. For example, one for frontend client and one for frontend admin.

Deploy both frontend separately, like, on netlify. And deploy the backend on backend service like heroku.

(Well you can deploy both the frontend apps on heroku but since heroku free tier has limited instance, you should deploy your frontend apps to other services and netlify is a perfect place for that).

But because you said MERN stack, so I assume your first application is tightly coupled to your backend. If that's the case, you can either:

1. Decouple the backend service as a public REST API, access the API for both frontend application.
2. Add a new route to the existing frontend app, let's say `/admin` for your new application. And develop all of your admin functionality on that route.

If you chose the former, MERN stack is not suited (I haven't used MERN so I might be wrong here), use vanilla react + expressjs server instead.

And as of now, MERN is now deprecated: https://mern.io/, so you might want to migrate to vanilla react + expressjs instead of using that.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. What if I add login functionality and create a model in the express backend with a boolean value for 'admin' such that when I enter my email to login/register, set the value of 'admin' to true?. In the frontend, I'll add a button such that if 'admin' === true, show the button to go to the admin dashboard. Is it security vulnerable?

Comment: I don't think I'm understand your question, but If I understand correctly, if you do login via admin page, you want to set the admin value to true, and after that, you can visit admin dashboard via frontend? How about just have a different account for admin/client? Or you can actually have the same account for both.

Comment: i have the same question here, please did you found the best approach for this ?

Comment: can you elaborate about what the "same" question you're having? because it's already been a year so more context will help @iskandar47

Comment: I mean @DhanmoniNath question, i’m looking for the best approach to create my dashboard .

Comment: if I were to create new dashboard-client system, I'll go with 2 frontend project and one backend project. With that we can actually have one user database that will incorporate different role (role='admin' -> can login to dashboard + client; role='user' -> can only login to client)

@iskandar47

Comment: 2 frontend project can goes into one repository, though, so let's say you have one big repo for both dashboard and client, and let the routing system handle the rest (client side routing), or 2 separate project in a "monorepo" that will be separated by reverse-proxy with nginx/apache (for example) in the server. tonnes of options @iskandar47